# How to get frames from video file in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to run tensorflow mobilenet model on a pre-recorded video. The only way I have found to extract frames is to use ffmpeg. But the thing is that I need to keep the app in expo. Is there any way I could get frames from the video and run the model on them?
Maybe by getting current frame from expo-av or something else.